# Turn horizontal delimited list to vertical list

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I'm trying to expand a delimited list vertically and would appreciate any help.  Hopefully the tables below will help explain what I'm looking to try and do.  The delimited lists are not capped to a certain amount of letters (could even have more than 3 types like i list below)

Example input

| Name | List |
| --- | --- |
| NameA | 3:F,1:G |
| NameB | 2:G |
| NameC | 1:F,1:G,1:J |

What I'm trying to out put

| Indexed Name | Letter |
| --- | --- |
| NameA_1 | F |
| NameA_2 | F |
| NameA_3 | F |
| NameA_4 | G |
| NameB_1 | G |
| NameB_2 | G |
| NameC_1 | F |
| NameC_2 | G |
| NameC_3 | J |

Please let me know if I need to clarify anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this in PowerQuery M

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source , "Letter", each List.Combine(List.Transform(Text.Split([List],","), each List.Repeat({Text.AfterDelimiter(_,":")},Number.From(Text.BeforeDelimiter(_,":")))))),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Name2", each let name=[Name] in List.Transform({1 .. List.Count([Letter])}, each name&"_"&Text.From(_))),
Combine = Table.FromColumns({List.Combine(#"Added Custom1"[Name2])}&{List.Combine(#"Added Custom1"[Letter])},{"Indexed Name","Letter"})
in Combine
```

[image]